# Change AD Username breaks ASP.MVC 3 web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, active-directory, iis-7.5, roleprovider

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web site that uses Windows Authentication running under IIS7.5. This web site also checks manually for groups in AD using the `GetRolesForUser` method of a custom `RoleProvider`. This isn't anything special, and has been working fine for a few months now.

However, we now have a user that had their Active Directory user name changed. They still have the same actual AD account, but to them their login name is now different.

Unfortunately this has broken the web site for this user. I'm using Elmah to log errors, and I have noticed that `REMOTE_USER` is using the old account name, and `LOGON_USER` is using the new account name. It looks like the `username` parameter of the `GetRolesForUser` method is getting the old account name - so I assume it is using `REMOTE_USER`.

Should I be targeting the web server or the web site for a fix? I've read that `LOGON_USER` and `REMOTE_USER` are only different if there is an authentication filter installed. I'm not aware of anything like this on the web server (although I'm not sure exactly where to look), but does MVC3 add this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical, after I posted, my Google-Fu kicked in.

Seems like this is a known issue (by design) with the local sid cache:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358

Resolution is to follow the registry change in article (and undo it again?), or reboot the web server. I have read that a `IISRESET` might fix this too.